# Botones en Datatable responsive no funciona en Angular

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-datatables

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Angular (Angular 17.1.2) usando DataTables responsive (librería angular-datatables v17.0.0) para mostrar los datos de una API. Sin embargo, todo funciona bien en el computador pero en móviles, los botones de la tabla no funcionan. He leído documentación en la página de los datatables pero salen soluciones nativas para datatables con Jquery.

[image: tabla responsiva]

Aquí está una tabla:

```js
public dtOptions:Object: {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      processing: true,
      language: {
        url: '../../assets/translate/es-dt.json',
      },
      dom: 'Blfrtip',
      buttons: [
        {
          extend: 'copyHtml5',
          text: '<span class="fa-solid fa-copy"></span>',
          titleAttr: 'Copiar',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: ':not(.actions)'
          }
        },
        {
          extend: 'excelHtml5',
          text: '<span class="fa-solid fa-file-excel"></span>',
          titleAttr: 'Excel',
          className: 'btn-excel',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: ':not(.actions)'
          }
        },
        {
          extend: 'csvHtml5',
          text: '<span class="fa-solid fa-file-csv"></span>',
          titleAttr: 'CSV',
          className: 'btn-csv',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: ':not(.actions)'
          }
        },
        {
          extend: 'pdfHtml5',
          text: '<span class="fa-solid fa-file-pdf"></span>',
          titleAttr: 'PDF',
          className: 'btn-pdf',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: ':not(.actions)'
          }
        },
        {
          text: '<span class="fa-regular fa-repeat"></span>',
          key: '1',
          action: function (e: any, dt: any, node: any, config: any) {
            document.getElementById('rerender-table')?.click();
          },
          titleAttr: 'Recargar tabla',
        },
      ],
      deferRender: true,
      responsive: true,
      stateSave: true
    }
```

```html
<table id="usersTable" datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"
            class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive table-sm" aria-label="Tabla de usuarios"
            style="width:100%">
            <thead [ngClass]="{'table-dark': darkmode}">
              <tr>
                <th scope="#">#</th>
                <th scope="fecha_movimiento">Fecha de movimiento</th>
                <th scope="tipo">Tipo de movimiento</th>
                <th scope="valor">Valor</th>
                <th scope="cuenta">Cuenta</th>
                <th scope="estado">Estado</th>
                <th scope="acciones" class="actions">Acciones</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody [ngClass]="{'table-dark': darkmode}">
              @for (movement of arrMovements; track movement.id; let i = $index){
              <tr>
                <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                <td>{{adminHelpers.getSimpleFormatDateWithoutTime(movement.paymentDate)}}</td>
                @if (movement.typeMovement == 'Ingreso') {
                  <td class="text-danger">
                    <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
                    {{movement.typeMovement}}
                  </td>
                } @else {
                  <td class="text-success">
                    <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>
                    {{movement.typeMovement}}
                  </td>
                }
                <td>${{adminHelpers.formatNumber(movement.paymentValue)}}</td>
                <td>{{movement.account.account_number}}</td>
                @switch (movement.status) {
                  @case ('0') {
                    <td>
                      <span class="badge bg-success">
                        <span class="fa-regular fa-circle-check fa-beat-fade"></span>
                          Pagado
                        </span>
                      </td>
                  }
                  @case ('1') {
                    <td>
                      <span class="badge bg-warning">
                        <span class="fa-regular fa-triangle-exclamation fa-beat-fade"></span>
                          Pendiente
                        </span>
                      </td>
                  }
                  @default {
                    <td>
                      <span class="badge bg-danger">
                        <span class="fa-regular fa-ban fa-beat-fade"></span>
                          Cancelado
                        </span>
                    </td>
                  }
                }
                <td>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary mr-1" (click)="showUserData(movement.id)">
                      <span class="fa-solid fa-eye"></span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </td>
                @if (movement.status == 'Error de conexión con el servidor.') {
                  <td>
                    Error de conexión con el servidor.
                  </td>
                }
              </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
            <tfoot [ngClass]="{'table-dark': darkmode}">
              <tr>
                <th scope="#">#</th>
                <th scope="fecha_movimiento">Fecha de movimiento</th>
                <th scope="tipo">Tipo de movimiento</th>
                <th scope="valor">Valor</th>
                <th scope="cuenta">Cuenta</th>
                <th scope="estado">Estado</th>
                <th scope="acciones" class="actions">Acciones</th>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
```

Claramente tiene la librería de el datatable responsivo en mi angular.json:
Estilos CSS:

```
"node_modules/datatables.net-bs5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-dt/css/responsive.dataTables.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-bs5/css/responsive.bootstrap5.min.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-dt/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-bs5/css/buttons.bootstrap5.min.css"
```

Scripts en angular.js:

```
"node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-bs5/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-responsive-bs5/js/responsive.bootstrap5.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons-bs5/js/buttons.bootstrap5.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.min.js"
```